# Breaking a string into smaller chunks

Tags: ruby, date

I have this string `s` that is formatted in this way. I want to turn it into a `Time` object.
Here is my attempt at doing this and making it readable.

```
s = "15081992"  
n = { :year=> s[4..7], :month=> s[2..3], :day=> s[0..1] }  
newtime = Time.mktime( n[:year], n[:month], n[:day] )
# 1992-08-15 00:00:00 -0400
```

It works, but I'm seeking any suggestion or feedback on how to write this in a better way to achieve the same result or is this pretty much it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'date'
Date.strptime("15081992", "%d%m%Y")
```